# Ruby - Printing a hash to txt file

Tags: ruby, hash

Need to print the following hash into a txt files with each key as the file name and each key's values as the content for each file.

hash

```
{ 'a' => [ 'abc' , 'def', 'ghi'] , 'b' => [ 'jkl' , 'mno' , 'pqr' ] }
```

The output files shall have the following format

a.txt

```
abc
def
ghi
```

b.txt

```
jkl
mno
pqr
```

Wondering how to go about this?

Comment: Do you want to create the file also dynamically? or file are already created ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit , yes the intent is to create the file dynamically.

Comment: Look at docs/tutorials for Hash#each, File.open, and File#puts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash = { 'a' => [ 'abc' , 'def', 'ghi'] , 'b' => [ 'jkl' , 'mno' , 'pqr' ] }
hash.each do |k,v|
  File.open("#{k}.txt", 'w'){|f| f.puts v}
end
```

Comment: it should be `f.puts *v`, [`IO::puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) takes its arguments as comma separated list..

Comment: It isn't necessary to "splat" the value. `puts` does the right thing when it sees an array. ["If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line."](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-puts)

Comment: @theTinMan I had missed the line.. Thanks.. Really Ruby is very smart.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `File.write`:

```
hash = { 'a' => [ 'abc' , 'def', 'ghi'] , 'b' => [ 'jkl' , 'mno' , 'pqr' ] }
hash.each { |k, v| File.write(k, v.join("\n")) }
```

Or:

```
hash.each { |k, v| File.write(k, v * "\n") }
```

If you want a carriage return at the end of the final line, then one of the answers using `puts` in a loop will work. Some applications care whether there is a trailing line-ending, others don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
hash.each do |key, vals|
  File.open("#{key}.txt", 'w') { |file| file.puts *vals }
end
```

Comment: I think you can skip the newline in ruby 1.9+

Comment: Just do `file.puts(*vals)`

Comment: +1 to puts *vals - @PinnyM: thanks! I had never noticed.

Comment: It's not necessary to "splat" `vals`. `puts` will take an array and iterate over it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.each do |key,value|

File.open("nameoffile.txt", "w"){ |file| file.puts value} #Opened file gets each value of correposnding hash key's

end
```

or just

```
hash.each_value do |value|

File.open("nameoffile.txt", "w"){ |file| file.puts value} #Opened file gets each value of correposnding hash key's

end
```

Comment: Please learn how to format your answer (or questions). The edit box has a nice [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that explains how it all works.