# Outputting hash to text file

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble outputting the contents of my hash to a file. The program is one that manages a list of student records, including their StudentID, first name, last name, Major, and catalog year. Once the user is finished adding records, it is then added to the hash.

Everything in the program works perfectly, except when I try running the quit_program function, it doesn't save the contents in the file. Additionally, i am not getting any errors, any ideas?

could it potentially not be working because it is having trouble with converting the text in my hash, which is alphanumeric, into the text file?

```
def quit_program()

puts "Save Changes? y/n"

@changes = gets().chomp

if @changes=="y"


    @fh=File.open(@file_name, 'w')
    @this_string=""

    @sDB.each do |key, store_account_data| #line 50

    puts "#{key}: #{store_account_data.join(',')}"
    end
    end 

@fh.puts(@this_string)
@fh.close()     

end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reread your question, and see if it's difficult to parse because your grammar, capitalization, and formatting are not what they should be. Consider this: The more difficult it is to read, the longer it takes for us to make sense of it, and, the less time you put into your question, the less time we are likely to spend trying to make sense of it. I'd recommend re-editing your question, improving the grammar and capitalization and formatting.

Comment: Post the entire contents of the source code, or a link to a gist, hackpad, etc., (eg. https://hastebin.com)

Comment: Don't paste "the entire contents" of code, or use a link. Stack Overflow requires the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem *in the question itself*. Links rot making the question worthless to future searchers and they waste our time having to chase them down just to see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing anything to the file. The string `@this_string` is empty. You should do

```
@sDB.each do |key, store_account_data|
  @fh.puts "#{key}: #{store_account_data.join(',')}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in the error message: `undefined local variable or method 'sDB'`. *(Which you have since removed from your question making the edited version next to impossible to answer.)*  Where and when is `sDB` defined in your program?  You are evidently attempting to quit before initializing it.

In any case it is not a good thing to be accessing instance variables directly inside other methods.  You should use accessor (getter and setter) methods instead.  That would have probably prevented this situation from biting you in the first place.

```
def sdb
  @sDB ||= Hash.new
end

def sdb=( key, value )
  sdb
  @sDB[ key ] = value
end
. . .
```

You are not properly writing to a file even if `@sDB` is defined.  See [Ruby - Printing a hash to txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241747/ruby-printing-a-hash-to-txt-file) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't save the contents in the file.

The following is NOT how you write to a file:

```
puts "#{key}: #{store_account_data.join(',')}"
```

That is how you write to your terminal/console window.

And this code:

```
    @this_string=""

@fh.puts(@this_string)
```

writes a blank string to the file.

Here is how you write to a file:

```
class Student

  def initialize(sDB, filename)
    @sDB = sDB
    @filename = filename
  end

  def save_changes()
    puts "Save Changes? y/n"
    user_answer = gets().chomp

    if user_answer == "y"

      File.open(@file_name, 'w') do |f|
        @sDB.each do |key, store_account_data| #line 50
          f.puts "#{key}: #{store_account_data.join(',')}"
        end
      end

    end 

end
```

> could it potentially not be working because it is having trouble with
>   converting the text in my hash, which is alphanumeric, into the text
>   file?

No.  Here is a concrete example you can try:

```
data = {
  "John" => ['a', 123, 'b', 456],
  "Sally" => ['c', 789, 'b', 0]
}

File.open('data.txt', 'w') do |f|
  data.each do |name, data|
    f.puts "#{name}: #{data.join(',')}"
  end
end

$ ruby myprog.rb 
$ cat data.txt
John: a,123,b,456
Sally: c,789,b,0
```

Also, ruby indenting is 2 spaces--not 0 spaces or 3 spaces, or anything else.

Comment: Also, variables are snake_case in Ruby, not camelCase, so `@sDB` needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing essential input data, so there's no way to test our suggested changes.

Here's untested code I'd work from:

```
def quit_program
  puts "Save Changes? y/n"
  if gets.chomp.downcase == 'y'
    File.write(
      @file_name,
      @s_db.map{ |k, v| "#{ k }: #{ v.join(',') }" }.join("\n")
    )
  end 
end
```

Note:

- `@sDB` isn't a proper variable name in Ruby. We use snake_case, not camelCase for variables and method names. ItsAMatterOfReadability. Follow the convention or suffer the wrath of your team members the first time you have a code review.
- Don't add empty parenthesis to method names (`quit_program()`) or calls (`gets()`) unless it's essential to tell the difference between a variable and a method invocation. You should also never name a variable the same as a method because it'll confuse everyone working on the code, so that should never be a consideration.
- Don't create a variable (`@changes`) you use once and throw away, unless what you're doing is so complex you need to break down the operation into smaller chunks. And, if you're doing that, it'd be a really good candidate for refactoring into separate methods, so again, just don't.
- When comparing user-input to something you expect, fold the case of their input to match what you expect. (`gets.chomp.downcase == 'y'`). It really irritates users to enter "y" and fail because you insisted on "Y".
- While you *can* use `File.open` to create or write to a file, there's less visual noise to use `File.write`. `open` is great when you need to use various options for the mode but for plain text `write` is sufficient.
- The whole block used for writing looks like it can be cleaned up to a single `map` and `join`, which coerces the data into an array of strings then into a single string.